# Get the properties of objects in array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have a small problem here.
I have an array which holds some objects (which have properties, duh)
Now I want to sort them by an int property that they have. My qustion is not how to sort them, but how do I read the value of the property of the objects in the array?

```
private void WriteHighscoreToFile(int groesse, int minenAnzahl, int zeit, string name)
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\tstadler\Desktop\Highscore.txt", true))
  {
    sw.WriteLine("Spieler: " + name + " Punkte: " + (groesse * minenAnzahl - zeit * 2) + " Groesse: " + groesse + " Minenanzahl " + minenAnzahl + " Zeit: " + zeit);
  }

  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\tstadler\Desktop\Highscore.txt", true))
  {
    List<CreateNewHighscore> highScores = new List<CreateNewHighscore>();
    while (sr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
      _objectProperties = sr.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      highScores.Add(new CreateNewHighscore(_objectProperties));
      highscoreCount++;
    }
    _highscoresArray = highScores.ToArray();
    vergleicheArray(_highscoresArray);
  }
}
```

The Class:

```
    public class CreateNewHighscore
      {
        public string _name;
        public int _punkte;
        public int _groesse;
        public int _minenAnzahl;
        public int _zeit;


     public CreateNewHighscore(string[] infos)
     {
       _name = infos[1];
       _punkte = int.Parse(infos[5]) * int.Parse(infos[7]) - 2 * int.Parse(infos[9]);
       _groesse = int.Parse(infos[5]);
       _minenAnzahl = int.Parse(infos[7]);
       _zeit = int.Parse(infos[9]);
     }   }
```

Comment: What is `CreateNewHighscore` class? Can you show its code, because your problem is not clear

Comment: you mean you have a problem to parse _objectProperties in CreateNewHightscore constructor, to set, for example, property Spieler ? If that's the problem, show use your CreateNewHighscore class, and what you have in ctor.

Comment: What Does new CreateNewHighscore(_objectProperties) do? Does it parse the string and populate properties on the object? If the array is typed you can use the indexer _highscoresArray[i].<YourProperty> Where <YourProperty> is the name of your property on the CreateNewHighScore type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My qustion is not how to sort them, but how do I read the value of the property of the objects in the array?

You expose it as a property; for example:

```
class CreateNewHighscore
{
    string _name;
    int _punkte, _groesse, _minenAnzahl, _zeit;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public int Punkte { get { return _punkte; } }
    public int Groesse { get { return _groesse; } }
    public int Zeit { get { return _zeit; } }
    public int MinenAnzahl { get { return _minenAnzahl; } }

    // constructor not shown
}
```

Then you can access that member from any array / list; for example:

```
highScores.Sort((x,y) => x.Punkte.CompareTo(y.Punkte));
```

or:

```
int firstPunkte = _highscoresArray[0].Punkte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method:

```
_highscoresArray = highScores.OrderBy(h => h.Punkte).ToArray();
```

Where `Punkte` is a property of your `CreateNewHighscore` class:

```
public int _punkte; // public field

public Punkte // public property
{
   get { return _punkte; }
   set { _punkte = value; } // you may not need setter
}
```

**BTW** currently your class DO NOT have any properties. There are only public (after your last edit) fields. If you want to sort by field value then:

```
_highscoresArray = highScores.OrderBy(h => h._punkte).ToArray();
```

But I advice you to make fields private, or use auto implemented properties instead. And rename your class. Name is really awful and sounds like method name.

```
public class CreateNewHighscore
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Punkte { get; private set; }
    public int Groesse { get; private set; }
    public int MinenAnzahl { get; private set; }
    public int Zeit { get; private set; }

    public CreateNewHighscore(string[] infos)
    {
       // check infos count
       Name = infos[1];
       Punkte = int.Parse(infos[5]) * int.Parse(infos[7]) - 
                2 * int.Parse(infos[9]);
       Groesse = int.Parse(infos[5]);
       MinenAnzahl = int.Parse(infos[7]);
       Zeit = int.Parse(infos[9]);
   }
```

}

Comment: I DONT want to know how to sort.

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler `h.PropertyName` is the part where you read property of `CreateNewHighscore` object

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of type `CreateNewHighscore[]` so if you want to access property in classic way just use following line.

```
_highscoresArray[i].YourIntProperty
```

where "YourIntProperty" is desired `int` property.

Comment: I think thats my problem, because It doesnt show me any properties.

Comment: Your properties are set to be `public`? By default they are `private` thus cannot be seen from outside of class

Comment: @Tim before the edit, they were implicitly private - and IMO, they were correct to be private (and incorrect to be public)

Comment: agree, except Tim's class contains fields, not properties. Your answer explicitely showed how properties should be set to public